# What is the circuit formation in this electric blackbox?

Tags: diodes, resistance

It should be a simple question from my exercise book, but I could not find the solution for some reason.

[image]

As illustrated, in an electric blackbox, there is one switch (k), one 3-volt battery, three 1-Ohm resistences, a diode. Now observe the blackbox with a voltmeter and a conducting wire.

When k is off (disconnected, or the switch k is off), U<sub>AB</sub> = 3V, U<sub>BF</sub> = 3V, U<sub>DE</sub> = 0V, U<sub>AF</sub> = 0V

Connect D, F: U<sub>CD</sub> = 0V, U<sub>AF</sub> = 1.5V

When k is on (connected), U<sub>EF</sub> = 1.5V, U<sub>DF</sub> = 1.5V

Connect C, A: U<sub>ED</sub> = 0V = U<sub>BD</sub>

Disconnect C, A, connect E, D: U<sub>AB</sub> = 2V

I think that to allow U<sub>AB</sub> to be 2V (when k is on and E, D connected), the circuit diagram at that point has to be equivalent to either of the below two:

[image]

However, I can not find any formation which would show the voltage readings mentioned in the question, when respectively k is on or off (with nothing else connected).

Does this question even have a solution?

Note: One may assume that the sign of the voltage can be ignored.

Comment: What does "k is off" mean? Disconnected from what?

Comment: Are you expecting us to surmise that "k" is the switch?

Comment: K is shown as a switch connected to terminal F

Comment: @Jasen, but the first line shows \$ U_{BF} > 0 \$ when the switch is off. That means it's not the only thing connected to F.

Comment: Also, I take it we're supposed to ignore the sign of the voltage. Otherwise, you can't have \$U_{AB}\$ = (+)3V, \$U_{BF}\$ = (+)3V, and then have \$U_{AF}\$ = 0V instead of 6V.

Comment: Either the sign or the convention about the **order** of subscripts...

Comment: @Transistor  "k is off" means that the switch k is off.

Comment: @Solar Mike k is the switch.

Comment: Can you post a good, clear, properly cropped photo of the question? It's not clear what's going on at F and how *k* is wired. See my comment to Jasen.

Comment: @Transistor The question is in another language. Regarding your comment to Jasen, I assume that a wire may connect a point between the switch k and F.

Comment: @DaveTweed I agree with you.

Answer (score 1):

Work in progress ...

*Table 1. Information supplied in table format.*

```
          a          b           c          d          e
        k off -------------    k on -------------------------
        DF disc.   DF conn.               CA conn.   ED conn.
        --------   --------    --------   --------   --------
U_AB    3 V *                                        2 V
U_AF    0 V        1.5 V
U_BD                                      0 V
U_BF    3 V *
U_CD               0 V
U_DE    0 V                               0 V
U_DF                           1.5 V **
U_EF                           1.5 V **
```

- and ** require that sign is not being reported.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fN7qHg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1. Our kit of parts and meter readings.*

Things we know:

- 3 V terminal voltage is from the battery with or without one or more series resistors and the forward biased diode (provided it isn't passing current).
- 2 V must be tapped off on the 3 Ω potential divider.
- 1.5 V must be a tapped off from a two resistor potential divider.